# Plot graphs with different x-axis Python

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some different distributions from simulation and from observed in the same graph. The lines represent the distribution of simulation and have values from 1 to 9, which are samplings following Benford's law.
And the bar chart, which is the observed distribution, has some missing values (3,4,5,6) and these values are from the first digit of all the elements in the variable `amount`. My final graph looks very strange. Could someone explain how to keep these missing values when I plot the bar chart? Thank you very much.

```
amount=np.array([1927.46, 27902.31, 86241.90, 72117.46, 81321.75, 97473.96, 93249.11, 89658.17, 87776.89, 92105.83, 79949.16, 87602.93, 96879.27, 91806.47, 84991.67, 90831.83, 93776.67, 88336.72, 94639.69, 83709.28, 96412.21, 88432.86, 71552.15])

np.random.seed(1000)

for i in range(10):
    u = np.random.rand(23)
    samples = np.floor(10**u)
    values,counts = np.unique(np.array(samples),return_counts=True)
    plt.plot(values,counts/np.sum(counts),color="blue",label="sample",marker="o",zorder=2)

amount = amount.astype("str")
first = [d[0] for d in amount]
values,counts = np.unique(np.array(first),return_counts=True)
plt.bar(values,counts/np.sum(counts),label="observed")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is (3,4,5,6) NA for missing values?

Comment: Where is your code.  You can't get help without posting your code and, ideally, some of your data.

Comment: Yes, (3,4,5,6) are missing values. But I would like to set them as zero in bar plot. Is there any good way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `values` for the bars are stored as strings. Matplotlib plots these strings like any other strings, placing them side-by-side on the x-axis starting at location 0 up to the last string at position 4 (bar for digit 9). You can verify this by adding `print(plt.xticks())` to your code just before `plt.show()`.

To solve this, you must use an array of integers. In the following example, this is done by changing the data type of `first`. In addition, the ticks are edited to show a tick label for each integer in the range of values:

```py
import numpy as np               # v 1.19.2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # v 3.3.2

amount=np.array([1927.46, 27902.31, 86241.90, 72117.46, 81321.75, 97473.96, 93249.11,
                 89658.17, 87776.89, 92105.83, 79949.16, 87602.93, 96879.27, 91806.47,
                 84991.67, 90831.83, 93776.67, 88336.72, 94639.69, 83709.28, 96412.21,
                 88432.86, 71552.15])

np.random.seed(1000)

for i in range(10):
    u = np.random.rand(23)
    samples = np.floor(10**u)
    values,counts = np.unique(np.array(samples),return_counts=True)
    plt.plot(values,counts/np.sum(counts),color="blue",label="sample",marker="o",zorder=2)

amount = amount.astype("str")
first = np.array([d[0] for d in amount]).astype(int)
values,counts = np.unique(first, return_counts=True)
plt.bar(values,counts/np.sum(counts),label="observed")
plt.xticks(range(min(values), max(values)+1))

plt.show()
```

[image: bar_plot_integers]